# Is this a good question? - How to write a description of a picture

Tags: discussion

Is this a good question for Writers.SE? Or should it go somewhere else? I thought Worldbuilding... but that doesn't seem right...

---

**What would be a short, comprehensive description for this picture?**

[Picture here]

---

The basic idea is Code Golf, but with descriptions instead of code.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking what to write, and that is off topic here.

You can ask for a good way to approach writing a description to a picture.

But please do not post an example image. If you do, I will vote to close, because I'd suspect that you'd be too lazy to do your own homework.